# Full-Calendar Automation using selenium

Tags: selenium, fullcalendar

how to do the full-Calendar automation using selenium.. in picture shown below i want to click on Marzp 26 at time 11:00 it is a jQuery plugin .. Please help

[image]

Comment: You will need to provide more details than that. What programming language? What's HTML of it? Is it a 'fancy' control like a Telerik RadCalendar or a jQuery plugin?

Comment: hi Arran it is a jquery plugin .. i want to automation it using selenium java ..

Answer (score 2):

Some of the grids in Fullcalendar can be tricky to work with because they are built in z-layers. One way to deal with this is to use selenium to move the mouse just like a user would.

This can be accomplished using action chains:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

# Get the row for 11:00:00
time_row = self.browser.find_element_by_css_selector('tr[data-time="11:00:00"]')
action = ActionChains(self.browser)

# Select the day by moving a fraction of the width of the <tr>
# In this case, I am moving to Wed on the 7-day agendaWeek view.
action.move_to_element_with_offset(time_row, time_row.rect['width']/2, time_row.rect['height']/2)
action.click()
action.perform()
```

Comment: Just to add on to this great answer!  If you haven't used action-chains before, you have to clear them after every use, or have multiple names for each action chain, as it gets cached.  So if you use it again with another offset, it will move the mouse from where you moved it previously instead of from the starting location again.

Comment: @MorganG and the method used for that ?

Comment: in his example it would simply be. action.reset_actions().

Comment: @MorganG I think for java, above method is not available

Comment: Ok honestly, this post was made 5 years ago, I haven't used Selenium in about 3 years, so I can't remember a lot about it.  I would just use stackoverflow to find your answer on how to reset actions in Java.